# Angular ui-grid - how to tell if I am on the last row

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using the latest version of [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) and am struggling with how to determine if the focus is currently on the last displayed row of the grid.

The data array is not sorted the way it is on-screen, so I cannot use that info. I read that the visible row cache should be sorted as it is on-screen, but I think that might be related to the old ng-grid. At any rate, if I look at `gridApi.core.getVisibleRows(myGrid)` it still has the sorting as per the raw data.

I am currently handling the event `gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate(newRowCol, oldRowCol)`. I can see the column and row that the user has the focus on, but I cannot see any values in this event (or elsewhere) that I can use to determine if the row is the last-displayed on-screen.  I'd appreciate any tips!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache which is an array sorted the way the rows are visible on the screen. You can then check if the row is the last row with something like:

```
oldRowCol.row.uid == $scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[$scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.length-1].uid
```

Comment: gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.renderedRows? This should work too